# Strange shader/material on all my cubes I created in blender 2.8

Tags: materials, shaders

Sorry if this is trivial but I can't figure out what this is and how I can disable it.
I have this strange shader/material (don't know which exactly it is) artifact on all my objects:

[image]

You see the outlines of the object and in the middle, it changes from a light gray to a dark gray. What is this? I tried deleting all materials on these objects but it's still there.

I have no lights and no camera.
It's there both in `solid` mode and in `LookDev` mode.

Please tell me if you need any more info. I genuinely don't know what this is and what info you need to help me

Thanks!

**Update**:
I made a brand new material and just changed the color to green and it's still there. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Update 2:
**Here's the project file**:

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell if it's an actual material or just a setting in your viewport without seeing the material setup for your model.

Comment: Does this help? https://imgur.com/a/TPe0Ggh
I created a brand new material and only changed the color and it's still there.

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135822/edit) link at the bottom of your question (i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to [add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) instead of linking them in the comments.

Comment: @cegaton - I know. Used it for quite a while now. It just so happened that I became aware of the mistake when the edit time limit kicked in.

Comment: Could you upload the file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and post the given link in your question? I cannot reproduce this shading in my version of Blender 2.80

Comment: I updated the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cropped the screenshot too tight so we can't see the shading settings on top of the screen.

That shading you see is just to help you see objects better in the 3D viewport, specially in solid mode, where you don't have materials to help you and it would be hard to distinguish shapes otherwise.

You have some control on how things are presented on the screen by clicking on the controls for shading. For solid view you can choose from several presets Flat, Studio or Matcap.
Among the setting and you can also choose to rotate the light source. In matcaps you can see the object with different textures.

[image]

For DevLook,is the same, you can visualize your object under different environments, or the actual light from the scene.

[image]

Note that this is not necessarily faithful representations of materials or lighting. Depending on your choice of shading for the viewer you might see a material that has nothing to do with the actual materials, but will help you visualize your object. will render or how the lights on the scnene are working. The light on final render will depend on the light sources and the environment. To make an assessment of the real materials and the actual lights of the scene use Rendered view.

Comment: thanks! Then I think I messed something up with the shading options. I tried changing stuff but it didn't change that the faces look strange. 

The thing is, if I add a new cube, it looks normal